# Javascript Ajax Post not sending special characters

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, special-characters

So I've been running into some problems when trying to send special characters though an ajax call.

```html
<textarea id="area" cols="70" rows="30"></textarea>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

```js
<script>
$('#submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var info = $('#area').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'pages/assignments/response.php',
        data: {area: info},
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

response.php:

```php
if (!empty($_POST['area'])) {
    $data = $_POST['area'];
    echo $data;
};
```

Comment: What does info contain exactly - `console.log(info);` - and what does a `var_dump($_POST['area']);` give you?

Comment: var dump using a exclamation mark gives me: string(3) "%21"

Console.log gives nothing when using special characters other than Post errors.